# Creating a Chess Board in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, chess

I am currently working on a chess game in android.

I am having difficulty with creating the actual chess board, could anyone suggest any ideas or provide any help?

Comment: Two-dimensional array? I really don't understand your question.

Comment: Yeah it will be a 2D array, but then i also need to get the pieces and the board onto the interface

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you having problems implementing the model of your game or its visualisation?

Comment: Provide some code of what you've done so far so we can give you more help!

Comment: We can't do your work for you. Some people make a living designing other people's software. Consider reading up on all the relevant documentation and trying out some ideas to see if they work. Be creative. If you get stuck on something *specific*, ask StackOverflow, and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a graphics engine If you would like to use models or primitive shapes (like drawing a sphere etc). I'd use open gl because of the support community).

Alternatively. Use A text based board. You can draw a textbox to screen using letters and symbols. Adjust the font size to have the board fill up the screen.

Eg. 
Ki,Q,B,Kn,T

Comment: Thanks for the help, but would i have the OnClickListners for the pieces or the board positions?

Comment: Use the onClickListeners on the pieces.

I would also implement this as a drop and drag functionality. Then detect the pieces new position and update the variables and refresh the screen.